# How to convert raw data to Cyrillic reading data in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to write a social bot for `vk.` Everything works, but when the bot gets an answer from a user - for example if the user writes in Russian (Cyrillic) - the answer is displayed like so:

```
    {u'count': 3441,
 u'items': [{u'body': u'\u041f\u0438\u0448\u0435\u043c \u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0432\u043a!',
   u'date': 1491934484,
   u'id': 7387,
   u'out': 0,
   u'read_state': 0,
   u'title': u' ... ',
   u'user_id': 23107592},
  {u'body': u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u0425\u0430\u0431\u0440!',
   u'date': 1491934479,
   u'id': 7386,
   u'out': 0,
   u'read_state': 0,
   u'title': u' ... ',
   u'user_id': 23107592}]}
```

My problem is that I cannot convert

```
{u'body': u'\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 \u0425\u0430\u0431\u0440!',
```

to a normal (Russian script) string that could be used later, for example - to analyse the user's answer.

Comment: Define a “normal string”. As far as I an see, your strings are as normal as strings get:
`a = u'\u041f\u0438\u0448\u0435\u043c \u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u0432\u043a!'; print(a)` — outputs “Пишем бота для вк!”

Comment: yeah, i found solution, i need just encode it to utf-8 encoding

Comment: not working try everything, but everything always fail script